# How can I make my point_in_polygon function more pythonic?

Tags: python, coding-style

I'm learning Python since 2 months and as I come from a more structured programming languages background (C/Java, JavaScript) I tend to code everything in a structured way instead pythonic way.

I copied the point_in_polygon function using "ray casting algorithm" from [here](https://observablehq.com/@tmcw/understanding-point-in-polygon) which is written in JavaScript and follows a perfect "structured programming style".

However, I changed it to Python:

```
def point_in_polygon(lat, lon, polygon):
    x = lon
    y = lat

    inside = False
    for edge in polygon:
        # i vertex
        xi = edge[1]
        yi = edge[0]

        # j vertex
        xj = edge[3]
        yj = edge[2]

        intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y)) and (
            x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi
        )

        # if intersections are an odd number, then the point is inside the polygon
        if intersect is True:
            inside = not inside

    return inside
```

But it doesn't satisfy me for Python. Is there any way to make this function look **more pythonic**? or even better using **numpy package**?

**EDIT***

Example of polygon input:

```
polygon = [
    [39.393037, -0.391826, 39.403516, -0.335521],
    [39.403516, -0.335521, 39.424338, -0.298442],
    [39.424338, -0.298442, 39.456420, -0.279903],
    [39.456420, -0.279903, 39.467950, -0.321788],
    [39.467950, -0.321788, 39.458806, -0.339469],
    [39.458806, -0.339469, 39.393037, -0.391826],
]
```

Each sub list inside the list represents an edge of the polygon and inside the sub list there is [lat1, long1, lat2, long2].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` to 'Pythonize' your function:

```
def point_in_polygon(lon, lat, polygon):
    p = np.array(polygon)
    inside = ((p[:, 1] > lat) != (p[:, 3] > lat)) &\
        (lon < ((p[:, 2] - p[:, 0]) * (lat - p[:, 1]) /
         (p[:, 3] - p[:, 1]) + p[:, 0]))

    return (np.sum(inside) % 2 == 1)
```

Note that I inverted your `lat` and `lon` parameters as it is more natural (at least for me) to give `(x,y)` instead of `(y,x)`. Moreover, I think you inverted `x`s and `y`s in your function (or it is possible I got confused with longitudes and latitudes).

Here is a MWE :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def point_in_polygon(lon, lat, polygon):
    p = np.array(polygon)
    inside = ((p[:, 1] > lat) != (p[:, 3] > lat)) &\
        (lon < ((p[:, 2] - p[:, 0]) * (lat - p[:, 1]) /
         (p[:, 3] - p[:, 1]) + p[:, 0]))

    return (np.sum(inside) % 2 == 1)


polygon = [
    [39.393037, -0.391826, 39.403516, -0.335521],
    [39.403516, -0.335521, 39.424338, -0.298442],
    [39.424338, -0.298442, 39.456420, -0.279903],
    [39.456420, -0.279903, 39.467950, -0.321788],
    [39.467950, -0.321788, 39.458806, -0.339469],
    [39.458806, -0.339469, 39.393037, -0.391826],
]

tests = [(round(x, 4), round(y, 4)) 
         for x in np.linspace(39.39, 39.47, 25)
         for y in np.linspace(-0.28, -0.40, 25)]

polygons = polygon[:]
polygons.append(polygons[0])  # To have a closed polygon when plotting
p = np.array(polygons)  # To make plotting easier
plt.plot(p[:, 0], p[:, 1])  # plot polygon
for tt in tests:
    inside = point_in_polygon(*tt, polygon)
    # plot test points, with color whether they are within the polygon or not:
    plt.plot(*tt, ls="None", marker="o",
             color="green" if inside else "red")
plt.show()
```